# Can I somehow get the value of query id of the stored procedure currently called inside that stored procedure itself in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Say I call a stored procedure like this:

```
call SP_TEST('CAT','LION');
```

Now post successful run I get the query id using the command:

```
select last_query_id();
```

This returns the query id as 01a07606-0b02-362d-0001-1d6602361072

Say I want this query id to be written to a variable during runtime - such as :

```
create or replace procedure test_proc111
("SRC" VARCHAR(30),  "TGT" VARCHAR(30))
returns varchar
language javascript
execute as owner
as '
{
var TABLE_VALUE = "";

    var code1 = "select last_query_id();"
    var code1_excecute = snowflake.execute({sqlText: code1});

    while(code1_excecute.next()) {
        var TABLE_VALUE = code1_excecute.getColumnValue(1); 
    }

    return TABLE_VALUE
}
';
```

Now I call this stored procedure like this:

```
call test_proc1111('TEST','TARGET')
```

But I get this error:

> Execution error in stored procedure TEST_PROC1111: Statement NULL not found At Snowflake. execute, line 8 position 31

How can we achieve this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the stored procedure in the question, you'll only get a query id if it's executed as caller:

```js
create or replace procedure test_proc111
("SRC" VARCHAR(30),  "TGT" VARCHAR(30))
returns varchar
language javascript
execute as caller
as '

var TABLE_VALUE;

var code1 = "select last_query_id(-1);"
var code1_excecute = snowflake.execute({sqlText: code1});
while(code1_excecute.next()){
    TABLE_VALUE =  code1_excecute.getColumnValue(1); 
}
return TABLE_VALUE
'
;
```

This because if it's defined at `execute as owner`, it will only have a previous query id if there is another query executed within the procedure:

```js
create or replace procedure test_proc111
("SRC" VARCHAR(30),  "TGT" VARCHAR(30))
returns varchar
language javascript
execute as owner
as '

var TABLE_VALUE;

var code1 = "select last_query_id(-1);"
var code1_excecute = snowflake.execute({sqlText: code1});

var code1 = "select last_query_id(-1);"
var code1_excecute = snowflake.execute({sqlText: code1});
while(code1_excecute.next()){
    TABLE_VALUE =  code1_excecute.getColumnValue(1); 
}
return TABLE_VALUE
'
;
```

Comment: This works, thanks. But can you give more details why execute as owner fails to achieve this functionality what we could fetch by caller?

Comment: Check https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-rights.html#session-state